# Two codes that should act the same sorting an array, don't

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Trying to sort the same array in ascending order.

I don't get the difference between these two codes. The results are different because in the second code the biggest number immediately goes in the last position, while in the first code the smallest number goes in the first position. It's like the opposite approach. But I don't get where is the difference in the code, maybe because I'm a newbie.

Also what's the best code of these two?

First code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(){
    unsigned int array[] = {3,1,9,6,0,54,4,12,52,44};

    for (unsigned int i=0;i<=SIZE-1;++i){
        for (unsigned int j=i+1;j<=SIZE-1;++j){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                int hold = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = hold;
            }
        }
        printf("At the @%d pass:\n", i);
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<=SIZE-1; ++k){
            printf("%d\n", array[k]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
At the @0 pass:
0
3
9
6
1
54
4
12
52
44

At the @1 pass:
0
1
9
6
3
54
4
12
52
44

At the @2 pass:
0
1
3
9
6
54
4
12
52
44

At the @3 pass:
0
1
3
4
9
54
6
12
52
44

At the @4 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
54
9
12
52
44

At the @5 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
54
12
52
44

At the @6 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
54
52
44

At the @7 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
54
52

At the @8 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @9 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54
```

Second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(){
    unsigned int array[] = {3,1,9,6,0,54,4,12,52,44};

    for (unsigned int pass=1;pass<SIZE;++pass){
        for (size_t i=0;i < SIZE-1; ++i){
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
                int hold = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = hold;
            }
        }
        printf("At the @%d pass:\n", pass);
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<=SIZE-1; ++k){
            printf("%d\n", array[k]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
At the @1 pass:
1
3
6
0
9
4
12
52
44
54

At the @2 pass:
1
3
0
6
4
9
12
44
52
54

At the @3 pass:
1
0
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @4 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @5 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @6 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @7 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @8 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54

At the @9 pass:
0
1
3
4
6
9
12
44
52
54
```

Comment: The first one looks like selection sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, the second one like bubble sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort. There is a difference, but not really an "opposite approach".

Comment: the second one start at 1 the firt one starts at 0? also your should create funtions for each algo

Comment: The inner loop starts at a different index. In the first code you swap using both the loop variables. In the second code, you only use the inner loop variable to do the swap, and the inner loop parses the whole array. They are not the same code, but they give the same end result. Different code - different partial sorts. Why would they be the same?

Comment: Note too that the first code took 9 passes to sort, the second code only 4 passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this snippet of first code:

```
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<=SIZE-1;++i){
        for (unsigned int j=i+1;j<=SIZE-1;++j){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                int hold = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = hold;
            }
        }
        .......
```

In this the element `array[i]` is selected and compared with rest all elements of array in the inner loop starting from `i+1` location and  swapped if it is greater than any element of `array[j]`. So, the smallest number in remaining array will go to the `[i]` location in array in every iteration. This is **selection sort**.

Look at this snippet of second code:

```
    for (unsigned int pass=1;pass<SIZE;++pass){
        for (size_t i=0;i < SIZE-1; ++i){
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
                int hold = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = hold;
            }
        }
        ......
```

In this, the inner loop compare two **consecutive** elements and if condition satisfy then they are swapped. This is **bubble sort**.